# Back button appears on popViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button, popviewcontrolleranimated

I am making an app in which I created custom navigation bar - **MyNavigationBar** (extends UIView):

***MyNavigationBar.xib*** :

[image: nib of that custom view]

***MyNavigationBar.m*** :

```
    +(id)navigationBar{
    MyNavigationBar * bar = (MyNavigationBar *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNavigationBar" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return bar;
}
```

Then in **NavigationViewController** implementation I use this code to add view showed above to **navigationBar**:

***NavigationViewController.m***:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _navBar = [MyNavigationBar navigationBar];
        [self.navigationBar addSubview:_navBar];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When the left button (subview of **MyNavigationBar**) is pressed

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

is called.

And the problem is that on that pop animation glitch happens, it looks like this:

[image][image]

Back button become visible for all animation duration and then disappears.

I have tried this but nothing happens:

```
[_navigationBar.backItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding custom subview to navigation bar try setting navigationItem.titleView to your custom UIView or use [UINavigationBar appearance] and [UIBarButtonItem appearance] APIs to customize standard controls.